# ValueError when I run a file in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, arguments

I am using Python 3 and have a little problem when running this file.

```
txt = input("Which file do you want to use?")
file = codecs.open(txt,"r","utf-8")


player=[]
name=None
longest_cast=0
result=[]

for line in file:
row=line.split()
row_1=len(row[1])
row_2=len(row[2])

if len(row)<5:
    mu=float(row[1])
    sigma=float(row[2])


    for r in range(0,6):
        cast=random.normalvariate(mu,sigma)
        result.append(cast)

if max(result)>longest_cast:
            longest_cast=max(result)
            name=row[0]

print("The winner is", name, "who got", longest_cast, "meters. Congrats! :)")
```

I get this error code.

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

What should I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like result is equal to [] and max([]) raises ValueError

Comment: You really need to fix your indentation here, python is whitespace sensitive so the indentation here could be causing your problems.

Comment: If your issue is solved, either delete your question if that's a possibility, or accept (or post) an answer. Removing your question content doesn't help anybody.

Comment: @deceze If the question is solved, deleting it is never good for anyone

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue here could be indentation related as python is whitespace sensitive. In the case where `max` is called with an empty sequence you will get an `ValueError`:

```
>>> max([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
>>> max('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

You need to check that `result` actually contains elements first.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the rows in your data file have at least five items, so none of the stuff indented under your `if` statement ever runs, including the `for` loop that appends to the `result` list. The argument to `max()` is thus an empty list and you get the error you indicate.

(There are other indentation errors in your code as posted, including one that will keep it from running at all.)